Find the equivalent resistance between \$A\$ and \$B\$
In the figure shown below, find the equivalent resistance.
I know I should add my attempt but I don't know how to approach these type of problems. This isn't the standard series-parallel combination and I am facing a lot of difficulty in doing this question.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Assuming each segment is 1 Ohm, the answer is 1 Ohm. Solve one layer at a time.

@Dereck can you pls tell how?? I will really appreciate that...this problem made me crazy for hours

I wish I could remember. Several years ago, I saw it in a lecture, and the speaker asked if anyone could solve it. I looked around and saw everyone's deer-in-the-headlights look, so I took an educated guess that said the above. Now, the instructor had a deer-in-the-headlights look and asked me how I knew that. I told him it was an educated guess based on where he was going with series/parallel circuits.
He then showed us how to solve it; all I recall is that he broke it down by layers. I did not need to remember how to solve it; I got the point of a series/parallel circuit complexity.

@Dereck I made you relieve your old memories :).....one question, do these problems have any practical application in electrical engineering or they're just made for Olympiads?

it is an exercise in futility to get the point across. It is like learning Ohm's law by solving hundreds of equations so you know the mechanics and relationship of current and voltage. That is how I guessed the answer was one. Number 1 is a magic number in Ohm's law and parallel circuits. If you have a 1-volt battery applied to a 1-ohm resistor, you have 1 amp of current flowing, making 1 watt of heat.

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad They are designed for these sports activists.

@periblepsis haha...heard of this for the first time

I’m voting to close this question because academic question need an attempt at a solution.

FYI: This problem is more at your level; you will learn some of the same concepts (tricks) without the tedium of this problem. https://youphysics.medium.com/the-resistor-cube-1dc1fa32ef00

@Mattman944 thanks for this

For this problem, you need to take advantage of the symmetry. The nodes that I have labeled in red are at the same potential by symmetry and can be connected together. All V1's can be connected together, all V2's can be connected together, etc.
Some are hidden on the other side making it more difficult.

Edit: I now believe that this is a very difficult problem meant as a challenge to the brightest students. Since this isn't typical homework, I am going to post my attempt. If there is a simpler methodology that I have missed, please let me know. Maybe someone who uses a simulator often can check my answer.
Redraw in two dimensions. Blue are 1 ohm, red are 3 ohm.

Assuming that I counted the resistors correctly, you get this network.

Which can be solved many ways, all more time consuming than I want to deal with manually.
I found a nice website to solve these types of networks.
Resistor Network Solver


I'll try and update..though it still seems a lot difficult

What!! This problem is meant for the brightest minds...I know I am nowhere near that level...but is it also difficult for an engineer!!!! Now I have no aspirations for solving this question but now I am even more curious to know the correct answer....in the comments above Dereck says that he remembers the answer as $1$ ohm ...which sounds quite convincing...409/330 isn't that appealing... I mean in competitions it is unlikely that they will give this as the answer....one more thing, i don't even know $0.0001%$ of engineering of what you know...  So pls don't take it as a rude comment

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Mattman944 has practically given the whole thing away to you. Suppose some points have the same voltage. V1 for example. Suppose you now take a wire and connect those points. (Three in this case.) Nothing has changed. That's because no current will flow in the wire since the voltages are all the same. So you can say that the resistance from point A to the joined three points with V1 must be 1/3rd of R. For example. Do you think you can move from there to the more complicated bits?

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad  And no, the answer isn't R. I think it may be 409/330*R. But I didn't double-check. I was too busy dodging the oncoming truck. ;)

For a double check, I put all 32 nodes and 60 resistors into the Resistor Network Solver tool. I get the same result.

Thanks to everyone who helped me
